# How to list audio files from a server

Tags: android

I want to get list of audio files from server that includes title, artist, album and cover art of that files and play audio file when user click on it in that list.
On the server we have a folder in the form of directory browsing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTrrX.png)

In the music folder I want to show folders in form of folder and I want to play audios by choosing. If necessary, we can change the server because our team has prepared it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would recommend you to ask your web team to provide you with a Json format URL where you will find all the information as shown in your image. 
If your team can provide that, you should be able to code your application to be able to download the Json data and display it however you like and add any functionality to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you have your own server or service where you are going to make that call from or are you in search of a public server with these details? If public, I would suggest going over to www.programmableweb.com and search for Music API.

Once you found it, I would suggest looking at Retrofit as this can be used in android to retrieve data from an API easily.